# problem c++ copy constructor of derived class and functions of the parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, shared-libraries, linear-algebra

I need to extend a linear algebra library for a neural network project. I need to add iterators and other functionalities to a matrix class. It's all done and working properly, but I have a problem with the assignment operator:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<blaze/Math.h>

namespace Dense{
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    template<typename Type, size_type Rows, size_type Columns>
    class Matrix : public blaze::StaticMatrix<Type, Rows, Columns, blaze::columnMajor, blaze::aligned, blaze::padded>{

    using StaticMatrix = blaze::StaticMatrix<Type, Rows, Columns, blaze::columnMajor, blaze::aligned, blaze::padded>;
    using nested_initializer = std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<Type>>;

    public:
        Matrix() : StaticMatrix() {}
        Matrix(nested_initializer list) : StaticMatrix(list) {}
        Matrix(const Matrix& other) : StaticMatrix(other) {}
        Matrix(const StaticMatrix& other) : StaticMatrix(other) {}
        virtual ~Matrix() {}

        Matrix& operator = (const StaticMatrix& other){
            this->operator=(other);
            std::cout << "copy";
            return *this;
        }

        Matrix& operator = (StaticMatrix&& other){
            this->operator=(other);
            std::cout << "move";
            return *this;
        }
    };
};

int main(){
    Dense::Matrix<float,2,2> A = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    Dense::Matrix<float,2,2> B = blaze::exp(A);
    std::cout << B;

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
    error: conversion from ‘const blaze::DMatMapExpr<blaze::StaticMatrix<float, 2, 2, true, blaze::aligned, blaze::padded, blaze::GroupTag<0> >, blaze::Exp, true>’ to non-scalar type ‘Dense::Matrix<float, 2, 2>’ requested
   36 |     Dense::Matrix<float,2,2> B = blaze::exp(A);
```

I can't find out how to use the parent class `=` operator for the base class.

Using the raw library is not an option, because I need to use it as a backend for existing code.

Any advice?

Comment: I find myself wondering when an assignment operator that uses itself to assign will ever end.

Comment: Are you certain that this is a good case for inheritance? Have you looked into composition?

Comment: @user4581301 I'll look for composition them... thanks.

Comment: If blaze is like Eigen, you want a templated assignment operator to cover the different expression types. Something like ```template<class Derived> Matrix& operator=(const blaze::DMatMapExpr<Derived>& o) { this->StaticMatrix::operator=(o); return *this; }``` There might be a better suited argument type. In Eigen, it would be ```Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>```

Comment: The crux of the problem is that while a `Dense::Matrix` is a `blaze::StaticMatrix`, a `blaze::StaticMatrix` is not a `Dense::Matrix` and the `Dense::Matrix` only has constructors that can accept an initializer list and a `Dense::Matrix`. The result of `blaze::exp(A);` may (probably is, but I don't know the blaze library) be be implicitly convertible to a `blaze::StaticMatrix`, but there will be no rule handing conversion to a `Dense::Matrix` unless you write one.

Comment: I just solved the issue with: `using StaticMatrix::StaticMatrix` instead of redefining all constructors.